# java Swing - Extending JComponent class to create text editor component

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I wish to create a text editing component by extending Java swing - JComponent class.

What should be the UI look and feel that should be set for this component?

I tried this:

```
public void updateUI(){
     setUI((TextUI)UIManager.getUI(this));
      invalidate();
}
```

However, this throws an exception:

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: com.gatech.ui.courier.TextComponent
```

TextComponent.java is my class that extends JComponent.

What am I missing? Is there any other way to create a text editing component of your own?

Comment: What don't you consider using *JEditorPane* or *JTextPane* or maybe override them to suit your needs?

Comment: @Sujay: Yep, why re-invent the wheel when it's right there for you to use!

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the method

```
public String getUIClassID() {
    return "TextPaneUI";
}
```

in your TextComponent. So you can get the UI from JTextPane. I think JComponent has no UI (and if any - it's not a TextUI).
But if you create your own component - you probably need to create custom UI.